# Prestashop 1.7 Exporting orders to XML

Tags: php, sql, xml, prestashop

Can you please help me with below script? It imports a specific order and displays in XML format.
The problem is that, a random records (product IDs) can be presented 2-times. As result I need to verify every time, whether the output includes the mistake or not. To sum up, how to improve this script in order to be sure that every output will be 100% correct?

```
<?php 
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    $xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
    // import Prestashop settings
?>
<ZAM>
<?php
$zamowienie = $_GET['zamowienie'];
$context = Context::getContext();
$id_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT', (int)$context->shop->id);
$order_details = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('
SELECT o.reference, o.date_add, o.id_order, message
FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders o
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'customer_message pl ON (pl.date_add = o.date_add)
WHERE o.reference = "'.$zamowienie.'"');

$order_details2 = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('
SELECT o.id_order, od.product_reference, od.product_quantity
FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders o
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail od ON (od.id_order = o.id_order)
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang pl ON (pl.id_product = od.product_reference)
WHERE o.reference = "'.$zamowienie.'"');

foreach ($order_details as &$od){
    echo "<NAG>";
        echo "<numer>".$od['id_order']."</numer>";
        echo "<data>".$od['date_add']."</data>";
        echo "<numer_zam>".$od['reference']."</numer_zam>";
        echo "<uwagi>".$od['message']."</uwagi>";
    echo "</NAG>";
}
foreach ($order_details2 as &$od){
    echo "<POZ>";
        echo "<numer>".$od['id_order']."</numer>";
        echo "<tw_id>".$od['product_reference']."</tw_id>";
        echo "<zam_ilo>".$od['product_quantity']."</zam_ilo>";
    echo "</POZ>";
};

?>
</ZAM>
```

Comment: Column orders.reference not unique so yeah there could be doubles. You've security breach, don't trust to user input and always escape it `Db::getInstance()->escape($zamowienie)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for indicating a security issue. I will fix it. My problem is caused by duplicated products in the database. How should I upgrade sql query in order to be sure, that only one product will appear in the output, even if it has more records in the database? Please take a look at below example.

```
<ZAM>
<NAG>
<numer>2045</numer>
<data>2020-04-22 17:51:04</data>
<numer_zam>HJJDHNTBV</numer_zam>
<uwagi/>
</NAG>
<POZ>
<numer>2045</numer>
<tw_id>7069</tw_id>
<zam_ilo>4</zam_ilo>
</POZ>
<POZ>
<numer>2045</numer>
<tw_id>7069</tw_id>
<zam_ilo>4</zam_ilo>
</POZ>
<POZ>
<numer>2045</numer>
<tw_id>98404</tw_id>
<zam_ilo>1</zam_ilo>
</POZ>
</ZAM>
```

This part of code appears 2 times due to 7069, the ID of duplicated product.

```
<POZ>
    <numer>2045</numer>
    <tw_id>7069</tw_id>
    <zam_ilo>4</zam_ilo>
</POZ>
```